# How can I edit this function call to scan only an half of the array?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int find_largest(int *, int );
int main(void) {
int a[] = {1,2,23,4,5,2,14,6,8,10};
printf("%d\n", find_largest (a, N));
 }

 int find_largest(int *a, int n) {
 int i, max;
 max = a[0];
 for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
 if (a[i] > max)
 max = a[i];
 return max;
 }
```

How can I edit the function call so that the program prints the maximum number of the second half of the array, so among these elements: {2, 14, 6, 8, 10}?
As I said, I should edit only this line:

```
printf("%d\n", find_largest (a, N));
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `N` relates to the size; and `a` to the start .. how can those be changed? (Hint: `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]` here, although using the indexer is not required.)

Comment: (The -1 is for not trying anything: attempting something and encountering grossly inaccurate results would have been better.)

Comment: Actually I tried several ways but I didn't write about that because I thought it was an easy problem for you...

Comment: It is an easy problem - but showing what has been tried makes easy problems better learning experiences. Not only can "the solution" be shown, the the incorrect/problematic attempt can be analyzed: e.g. *why* didn't it work? was it close to working? was it based on a flawed understanding of the problem or was it just a silly typo?

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll remember that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change that line as:

```
printf("%d\n", find_largest (a+N/2, (N+1)/2));
```

The `(N+1)/2` can handle the exception when `N` is an odd number.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 printf("%d\n", find_largest (a, N));
```

to

```
 printf("%d\n", find_largest (a + N/2, N/2));
```

Comment: What if `N` is an odd number?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: Good point. I guess you would either need 'a + N/2 + 1` or `N/2` then, depending on what you would consider your 'second half' in an array with an odd number of items.

Answer (score 0):

printf("%d\n", find_largest (a+N/2, (N+1)/2));

Comment: Output is: 2147344384 ... I don't think this is the right way to do this :\